# get alle events where date is in the past

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a mysql database with a table "events".
I get all data with:

```
SELECT * FROM `events`
```

There is an column "start" which has this value (example)

```
20210501T180000
```

Definition:

```
YYYYMMDDTHHIISS
```

Now I would like to get all data where the difference from date "start" and today is < 0 days.

For example:

```
start = 20211005T180000
today = 20211006T100000
=>  -1 day difference
```

the time should not be a factor.

Comment: Why are you not using `date` or `datetime` type for your column? Then the comparison will be simply a case of comparing to now()

Comment: Not the best way for my situation

Comment: Really? I've never come across a use case where storing a date as a string was an advantage. What exactly do you think you're gaining? Because you're losing quite a lot. These types exist for good reasons.

Comment: @Adyson It may just be for legacy reasons, in a project that has been developed over a decade and has enough depenedencies that it cannot be changed by the OP - the question still has a straight foreward answer.

Comment: @nos maybe, maybe not. If it's a new piece of work, then just changing to using a datetime column will be better, and more efficient in the long run, than doing the string comparison. That's why I asked OP for the reason.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that 'today' is the 10th June

Answer (score 1):

Today is 10th June...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_bad_data;

CREATE TABLE my_bad_data
(bad_date CHAR(15));

INSERT INTO my_bad_data VALUES
('20210501T180000'),
('20210610T180000');

SELECT * 
  FROM my_bad_data 
 WHERE DATE(STR_TO_DATE(bad_date,'%Y%d%mT%H%i%s')) < CURDATE();

+-----------------+
| bad_date        |
+-----------------+
| 20210501T180000 |
+-----------------+
```

As OJ mentions, if you can fix your schema, you should do so.

Comment: Notice this:  if your dates were stored in standard format, you could do stuff like  `WHERE date < CURDATE()`. That's good because it's easy to read, and because it can exploit an index on the `date` column. You'll be able to use the [dbms's date/time arithmetic functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html).